# Is there any way to access disabled textbox in selenium?

Tags: selenium, search, selenium-webdriver, textbox, webdriver

Recently i saw that google changed its home page and made searchbox diasable so i am not able to use inorder to provide text in searchbox:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("gs_htif0")).sendKeys("Toi");
```

Note : Flag value of searchbox: `disabled =""`

PFB Selenium code :

```
public class Navigation {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\resources\\"+"chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        if (driver.findElement(By.id("gs_htif0")).isEnabled()){
            System.out.println("This is siddhant");
            driver.findElement(By.id("gs_htif0")).sendKeys("Toi");
            /*driver.navigate().back();         
            driver.navigate().forward();*/

        }
        else {
            WebElement textbox = driver.findElement(By.id("gs_htif0"));
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].enabled = true", textbox); 
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gs_htif0']")).sendKeys("Hello");
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            textbox.sendKeys("hello");          
        }       
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. There is no element with an id of gs_htif0 on the google.com page. BUT... the search box is clearly there and not disabled otherwise no one would be able to do searches. The ID of the searchbox can be found using devtools in your favorite browser. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want to do is to remove the `disabled` attribute in `else` block

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("$('#gs_htif0').removeAttribute('disabled')"); 
textbox.sendKeys("hello");
```